# Why is this define directive seem to not be working?

Tags: c

I am a rookie programmer here. I am trying to learn C. I am trying to have a main program run another file. However, I am getting compile time errors. My IDE says: Error. Implicit declaration of function print and also it says ROW and COL are not defined here. Of course I have 3 files and I don't see why I am getting these errors. I think I defined ROW and COL properly in the header file like you're supposed to. Can someone see a problem with this simple code? Right now I have the following code:

```
//p750_eightqueens.h
#ifndef P750_EIGHTQUEENS_H_INCLUDED
#define P750_EIGHTQUEENS_H_INCLUDED
#define ROW 8
#define COL 8

void go(int row, int col);

void print(int array[ROW][COL]);

#endif // P750_EIGHTQUEENS_H_INCLUDED

//p750_eightqueens.c

void go(int row, int col) {
int a[ROW][COL],i,j;
for(i=0;i<ROW;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<COL;j++){
        a[i][j]=(i==row&&j==col?1:0);
    }
}
print(a);
}

void print(int array[ROW][COL]) {
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<ROW;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<COL;j++){
        printf("%i",a[i][j]);
        if (j!=COL-1) printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
} 
//now in main.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "p750_eightqueens.h"

int main(){

go(4,4);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: tl;dr.  try to boil it down to the gist.

Comment: And does `p750_eightqueens.c` actually contain an `#include "p750_eightqueens.c"` line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include your header file in `p750_eightqueens.c`, too.
Your `.c` files are compiled independently of each other, so your `p750_eightqueens.c` doesn't know about your defines and function declarations.

If you compile a C-program each compilation unit (`.c`-file) is compiled on it's own and needs all includes and declarations that are used in that file. After that you have object files (`.o`) which are then combined to a single executable by the linker. The linker searchs for the implementations of the used functions and puts it together so that different compilation units can call functions in others.

Comment: Thank you. This is the first time I have added other files to my program so sorry if it was a dumb question.

Comment: I added some explanation in case you're not familiar with the compiling process in C.